# Unity 2d game movement script issue - unable to jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically, after hours of torment trying to create basic movement script for simple platformer game I succeeded, but not quite. Square character is able to move around and jump just ok, but sometimes it won't jump, usually while moving on short distances or, rarely, standing in place and trying to jump. I can't figure out how to fix that. Here is entire script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rgdb2;
public float movementSpeed;
public float jumpHeight;
private bool isJumping = false;



// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    rgdb2 = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    HandleMovement(moveHorizontal);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == false)//by typing Space player jumps, cant double-jump
    {
        rgdb2.AddForce(new Vector2(rgdb2.velocity.x, 1 * jumpHeight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        isJumping = true;

        Debug.Log("jumped");
    }
}

private void HandleMovement(float moveHorizontal)//applying player horizontal controls and customing player's speed by movementSpeed variable
{
    rgdb2.velocity = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * movementSpeed, rgdb2.velocity.y); 
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.transform.tag == "Platform") //if player is touching object with Platform tag, he can jump
    {
        Debug.Log("on ground bitch");
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

}

It may not be that important, but I want to polish this game as much as possilble, even if I don't need to, since it's basically my first game made in Unity3d with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing to keep in mind: Unity3D Engine's inputs are only updated during the time the engine calls `Update()` methods for your GameObjects.

What this means is that you **should not** read any type of input in the `FixedUpdate()` method. Methods like [GetKeyDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) and other methods from the Input class which read keyboard/mouse/axis buttons/values should not be called during `FixedUpdate()`, as their returned values are unreliable.

Due to this, what is probably causing your jump implementation to fail is that the [GetKeyDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) method you're calling in `FixedUpdate()` is returning inconsistent/invalid (`false`) results, when the user presses the jump key.

Fixing this can be quite simple. I suggest you keeping a boolean variable which keeps track of whether the jump key has been pressed, and gets its value updated during `Update()`. This should fix your problem.

```
bool jumpKeyPressed;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        jumpKeyPressed = true;
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        jumpKeyPressed = false;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    /* Update "moveHorizontal", call HandleMovement(...) here, as you've already done. */

    if (jumpKeyPressed && isJumping == false)
    {
        // IMPORTANT: this prevents the "jump force" from being applied multiple times, while the user holds the Space key
        jumpKeyPressed = false;

        /* Remaining jumping logic goes here (AddForce, set "isJumping", etc) */
    }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE. I just tried and indeed my problem was solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your logic for jumping is inside **FixedUpdate()**

When you use **GetKeyDown** to register input make sure to use Update instead because if you press the key using **FixedUpdate** it may or may not run during that frame, test it with Update instead.

You already have in comments how Update works, it is called every frame but FixedUpdate according to [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html): This function is called every **fixed** framerate frame

```
void Update ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    HandleMovement(moveHorizontal);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == false)//by typing Space player jumps, cant double-jump
    {
        rgdb2.AddForce(new Vector2(rgdb2.velocity.x, 1 * jumpHeight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        isJumping = true;

        Debug.Log("jumped");
    }
}
```